# Getting "sed: -e expression #1" when trying to run search and replace

Tags: linux, sed

I'm using Amazon Linux.  I'm trying to run a search and replace using sed.  I'm running into the below error ...

```
[jboss@mydevbox nodejs]$ sed -i -e "s/test.smokeTest('(.*?)', '(.*?)', '(.*?)')/test.smokeTest('username', 'password', 'http://localhost:8081/myproject')/g" test.js 
sed: -e expression #1, char 96: unknown option to `s'
```

Not sure what I need to do to fix the issue above, only that there's something going on with my use of single quotes and double quotes.

**Edit:** This is the example file I'm using

```
//Creates the new browser and Logins in
console.log('Validation Complete');
var test = require('./js/Optimus.js');

test.smokeTest('####', '####', 'http://mydomain.com/myproject/');
```

Comment: Backwhack those HTTP slashes inside the `s///`

Comment: What's `'(.*?)'` supposed to match ? `'####'` ? It'll never match that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

- The last double quote you used is `”` change it to `"`.

Then:
The main issue is that you are using `/` for the `s` option of sed but your string also contains (un-quoted) `/`. The simplest solution is to change to `#` for the `s` delimiter, as this:

```
sed -i -e "s#test.smokeTest('(.*?)', '(.*?)', '(.*?)')#test.smokeTest(‘username’, ‘password’, 'http://localhost:8081/myproject')#g” test.js
```

I also believe you should solve this:

- You are using `‘` and `’` around `username` and `password`. Change them 
  to `'`.

---

#### Edit for new file.

For the file you just added to your question, you need to escape the parenthesis and remove the `?`:

```
sed -i -e "s#test.smokeTest('\(.*\)', '\(.*\)', '\(.*\)')#test.smokeTest('username', 'password', 'http://localhost:8081/myproject')#g" test.js
```